# include loading webpages in slideshow

Tags: php, slideshow

I am totally new to stackoverflow. I'm trying to adjust an excisting script in which an folder containing photo and video is getting loaded and displayed like a slideshow.

I'd like to add the option to load webpages also. Is there any easy way to do this?

Thank you so much.
This is my code:

```
<?php

include "class.getFiles.php";

$images = new getFiles();
// list of all files in the images folder (includes videos)
$imageArray = $images->getImageArray();

$sortedImages = new sortFiles();
$sortedImages->sortImageArray($imageArray);

// remove files not in the correct time period
$imageArray = $sortedImages->getImageArray();
$randImage = $sortedImages->randomImageNum();

$fileName = $imageArray[$randImage];

$info = new SplFileInfo($fileName);



?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fiction Slideshow</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
<?php 

if($info->getExtension() == "mp4")
{
    echo '<video id="vid" class="videoDisplay" autoplay>
  <source src="images/'.$fileName.'" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>';

   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
    vid.addEventListener("ended", function(){
        window.location.reload();
    });
   </script>';

}
else
{
    echo '<img class="imageDisplay" src="images/'.$fileName.'" />';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload();
    }, 30000);
   </script>';

}
 ?>
</body>

</html>
```

**This is the class.getFiles.php file that the other script calls.**

```
<?php
```

class getFiles{

```
protected $dir;
protected $imageArray;


function __construct()
{
    $this->get_dir();
    $this->get_images();
}

protected function get_dir()
{
    $this->dir = getcwd();
}

protected function get_images()
{

    if(count(scandir($this->dir."/images")) != 2)
    {
        $this->imageArray = scandir($this->dir."/images");
    }
    else
    {
        die("There are no files in the directory");
    }

}



public function getImageArray()
{
    return $this->imageArray;
}
```

}

class sortFiles{

```
protected $sortedImageArray = [];


public function sortImageArray($imageArray)
{
    foreach ($imageArray as $imageFile ) 
    {  
        if($imageFile !== ".." && $imageFile !== ".")
        {

        $imagePath = $imageFile;
        $imageFile = (substr($imageFile, 0, -4));
        $BeginningPos = strpos($imageFile, '_');
        $beginningDate = (substr($imageFile, 0, $BeginningPos));

        $beginningDateformatted = str_replace("-","/", $beginningDate);

        $stringToStartTime = strtotime($beginningDateformatted);


        $EndingPos = strpos($imageFile, '_', $BeginningPos  + strlen('_'));
        $EndingPos = $EndingPos + 1;
        $EndingDate = (substr($imageFile, $EndingPos));
        $EndingDateformatted = str_replace("-","/", $EndingDate);
        $stringToEndTime = strtotime($EndingDateformatted);

        $time = time();

        if($time <= $stringToStartTime && $time >= $stringToEndTime)
            {
                array_push($this->sortedImageArray, $imagePath);

            }

        }

    }

}

public function getImageArray()
{
    if(count($this->sortedImageArray) != 0)
    {
        return $this->sortedImageArray;
    }
    else
    {
        die("There are no files in the time range");
    }
}

public function randomImageNum()
{
    $imageArrayLength = count($this->sortedImageArray);
    $imageRand = rand(0, $imageArrayLength-1);
    return $imageRand;
}
```

}

?>

Answer (score 0):

Well you can save the web pages as links within your media folder. For example if you want to display the web page http://www.example.com, then you can create a file webpage1.txt inside the media folder. This file can have the link http://www.example.com.

In your code you can add a new condition that checks if the file type is txt. If the file type is txt, then your code can read the link inside the file and display the link using an iframe. The following code should work:

```
else if(strpos($fileName, "weblink") !== false)
{
   /** The path to the web page link */
   $file_path     = (getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "images" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName);
   /** Read contents of file */
   $web_page_link = file_get_contents($file_path);
   /** Display the link in iframe */
   echo "<iframe src='".$web_page_link."' width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>";
}
```

The above code should go above the else statement

Comment: Thank you so much Nadir. I'm going to try it and i'll let you know if it worked. Again thank you!!

Comment: It didnt work. I think it's the "class.getFiles.php" that is causing the problem. I'll put the code to that file in my original question. Could you please help me out why it didnt work? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try to put the web page files inside a folder called  "webpages". Try the above code again. I have updated it. It should go above the last else statement in the first example file that you posted.

Comment: Dear Nadir, turns out i made a mistake myself. The original script uses line of code that makes it nessecary to give all the files in the images folder a unique name to be dsplayed correctly. e.g: 12-31-2017_Example-Slide6_01-01-2015.png.txt. The script now loads the iframe in the slideshow without even making the whole webpages folder. The problem now is that i see that the slideshow is loading the iframe, but it doesnt work. i only added the link to the txt file like this: 'http:// www. stackoverflow.com'. Do i need to make any changes? Thank you for your time!

Comment: @JD10081986. You are welcome. I am just trying to help out. What error are you getting in your slideshow when loading the iframe ?

Comment: I'm only getting a blank iframe. I can see it loads the iframe, but no content what so ever. I've tried to change the " src='".$web_page_link."' " to a normal weblink and that works. So my guess is that the problem is with the $web_page_link or " file_get_contents($fileName) " code. If you like you can review the original code of the creator on github here: https://github.com/camling/digitalSignage

Comment: As I understand the slideshow code that you are using requires placing the images files inside an images folder. The file name should have a start data followed by some text and followed by an end data. If the current date  is within the start and end dates, then the image file is displayed. Here is an example of the file name: 09-29-2016_My fav image_11_03_2016. So your files containing the web page links should have the same naming convention. The files should be added to the images folder. I have updated my code

Comment: I already gave the txt file the correct naming convention, that was ok. I've put the txt file in the images folder and updated the script with your code. The slideshow only displays a big icon of a image that couldnt be loaded. :-(